# Current version of Http 1.1 reference documentation

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, embedded-jetty, http-1.1

I am working on my graduate thesis about RESTful web services in Spark micro framework and I want to talk a little about HTTP 1.1 protocol specifically HTTP methods. Problem is I am a bit confused with the reference documentation cause till now in my graduate thesis I've used HTTP 1.1 RFC2616 as my reference documentation but I see that there is a lot of new updated versions like RFC7230 and I am confused which one is the current one that is used. I am currently using jetty-9.4.4.v20170414 as my server and I can see that the server uses HTTP 1.1 but I am not sure if I am describing the right version of HTTP used in my jetty server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2616 has been obsolete since June 2014, when they released 723x. Each of 7230-7235 have a section at the end that describes what changes there are since 2616. I can't speak to what's being used in Jetty, but there are not many substantiative changes between the documents, so if that version of Jetty is relatively recent, I'd expect it conforms to the new specs. Have you tried asking the Jetty authors?

Comment: Jetty 9.4.x default configuration is for the RFC 723x series.  But it can be configured down to use the RFC2616 series with some modest effort.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt You should make that an answer so you can be upvoted! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. @EricStein for answering. I haven't asked the Jetty authors, honestly didn't even know you can ask and get a response, but from now on I'll definitely try that with future problems. Thanks again! ^_^

Comment: Thank you a lot Mr. @JoakimErdfelt too for clarifying that for me! ^_^